# Парсер съедает упоминание автора вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Невозможно сделать @упоминание автора вопроса в комментарии. При публикации комментария @упоминание пропадает. Автодополнение @упоминания в этом случае не работает вне зависимости от того, участвовал ли автор вопроса в комментировании или нет. Проверено на [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413977/c-linux-%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) вопросе. Возможно, аналогичное поведение будет с ответами.

Comment: fori1ton, а можно удалять `@`, тогда парсер не съедает имя, и его можно использовать, как обращение — как в этом примере.

Comment: Задубликатил к более новому вопросу, потому что там более подробный ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так и задумано. Поскольку автор ответа (или вопроса) всегда получает оповещение о комментариях, ненужный @ автоматически удаляется (если никто больше не участвовал в обсуждении). Не все довольны этой практикой, но она такова. Подробности на английском:  [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Немного непривычно, на ХэшКоде я использовал @упоминания не ради того, чтобы отправлялось уведомление, а просто как вводное слово, обращение. Что ж, будем привыкать к новым правилам.