# Модератор Grundy сомнительной адекватности

Tags: поддержка, модерация, модераторский-произвол

Вопрос -- [**Z-index по событию omouseover**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1547711/z-index-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E-omouseover)

Здесь разные стороны надо осветить. Первый пришел @Инквизитор. Посмотрел 2 минуты, указал проблему -- работай не с текстом , а с внешним DIV. Четко, просто, спасибо ему.
Пришел Grundy -- закрыл вопрос. Не в первый раз ! Основание  "НЕ ПО ТЕМЕ" !
Что такое "НЕ ПО ТЕМЕ" ??  Я же не рецепт простокваши спрашиваю.
Любой вопрос, где встречаются три буквы CSS -- уже по теме для этого сайта.
Уберите вы это основание, чтобы у модеров было меньше поводов для "законного" закрытия вопросов.

Я уже почти привык к закрытиям на stack.  Предположил, что ТЕМА не соответствует содержанию. Стал менять тему, слова подбирать, местами переставлять. И началось -- ты меняешь тему, как тебе ответить, ты всех запутал.
По сути, вопросы простые, может, сложные по исполнению. Но уже упрекать меня в том, что не понятна сама тема вопроса -- это надо быть либо идиотом, либо иметь свой интерес для принудительного закрытия.
Я вижу, что чем дальше, тем "ближе" открытие вопроса :) .

Почитайте чат, там 12 (!) экранов текста ! На такой плевый вопрос. Половина из них -- ответы типа "ищи проблему, и найдешь", "Анимация?", "Какая Анимация ?" , "где Анимация?" , "ты о чем ?"  ... и так на 12 экранов !!!
Конечно, отсюда не видно человека, но полное впечатление, что этот модератор Grundy просто развлекается так, весело ему. Время потрачено уйма, даже чертового света сожжено за 4 суток.

Или у него такой воспитательный эффект достигается ? Отец родной ...

Это сейчас вопрос выглядит просто. Он скопирован с сайта, там лишних стилей сотня. Для упрощения себе жизни, я несколько часов удалял стили, div, попутно восстанавливал нерабочий вопрос. На все это время ушло. Я не знаю, видел он ошибку сразу или нет, но @keyframe написаны мной, стоят отдельно в самом начале стилей, прямо под :root{}. Ошибка была снаружи и до чистки. Хорошо, время убито, стили почищены.

А в чем же ошибка ? Она не просто доступна для обозрения, она еще и зафиксирована, заблокирована:

```
 75% {transform-origin: center bottom
```

там в этих @keyframe свойства идут подряд. Далее следует transform: -- вы знаете, у него много внутренних свойств , которые НЕ отделяются (;) , вот transform-origin: ... должно заканчиваться  (;) . Но они идут в столбик. Визуально одинаковые. Конечно, тут можно проглядеть.
Из-за отсутствия этой  (;) , конечно, анимация @keyframe не работает.

В итоге, на 4 сутки Grundy сказал, ищи проблему в стилях. Ну если человек  сразу не видит, то он найдет ошибку, только когда 100 раз ее пройдет. Я бы ее нашел, на 5 сутки. Только не такой ценой!
Да, он первый заметил. И вот 12 экранов обсуждений, 4 суток я тупо смотрю в код, Grundy тупо ржет и 10 раз спрашивает про "какую Анимацию ?"  Из-за одного (;) убито времени немеряно. Ошибку я нашел. Он доволен, я счастлив. 4 суток убито.

Потом у него что-то клинит, он откатывает вопрос к состоянию  С ОШИБКОЙ (!!!). Представьте, на stackoverflow.com зафиксирована известная ОШИБКА, с ПОПУстительства модератора, заблокирована для потомков.
Мне понижена репутация , минус 2. Хорошо. Я своей BOUNCE поднял себе репу до 100, пусть снижает.
Я в полном афиге. Получаю требование создать новый вопрос. С другой темой ???? (я не понял зачем).

Хорошо, копировать я умею. 5 минут, второй вопрос

[**Совмещение omouseover="", :hover и transition:**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1548975/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-omouseover-hover-%D0%B8-transition)

создан, еще почищен. Эта чертова (;) поставлена.
Теперь новая проблема -- @keyframe работает, hover работает, transition сдохла. Мне опять менять тему ? Опять какой-то предлог. И НОВЫЙ вопрос закрыт через 5 минут после создания. Опять понижена репа на минус 2. У меня репутации много, я готов к 3 вопросу и предвижу блокировку аккаунта за дубли.

Я даже не в курсе, виден вопрос ? Или как в комментах на YouTube и отзывах Яндекс -- свои тексты видишь только ты сам.

Посмотрите мои вопросы и ответы, на них же :) У меня как минимум 2 вопроса, на который изначально было ясно, что никто не ответит -- Анимацию BOUNCE я не запятую нашел, я полностью просчитал все параболы в EXCEL (кому интересно, можно перевести в JS). Я сделал, за 2 дня, когда стало понятно, что как считать, и что "никто кроме меня". 2 вопрос про браузер на CSS, хотя мне кажется он проще. Но никто этого делать не будет. Ходил на профильный форум, 2 местных чела отказались.
Я про то, что если у меня есть вопрос, то я сам его решу (возможно :) ).

Еще, Grundy постоянно говорит о защите интересов новый юзеров, которые выиграют, если НЕ прочтут мой вопрос, в нем пользы нет! Как нет? Не надо тебе transition -- скопируй просто готовый onmouseover с функцией. Нафиг этот transition. А у меня вообще не вопросы, а конфетки. Не интересен  тебе onmouseover -- бери рабочий :hover с transition из соседнего вопроса. Лепота!
Но они закрыт и будут удалены.
Где тут забота о подрастающем поколении? Не забота, а вредительство.

Короче, как я устал от этих качелей. Пишу -- оставь мои вопросы в покое, без тебя ответят. Эти мои комменты удалены им же.

В конце концов, на stackoverflow.com приходят за помощью. А не психологическим давлением и принудительным обучением. Знаешь ответ -- подскажи. Не знаешь -- дай другим спокойно читать вопросы и зарабатывать благодарности.

Я испытал сильную психологическую травму. Мне такая помощь, такой ценой не нужна. Своим временем кому-то поднимать настроение. Подобные действие Grundy [**не однократны**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141638/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167------). Человек способен зарабатывать себе звездочки, а вот модерировать -- это вряд ли. Пусть отдохнет от непосильного беремени работы в коллективе. Не педагог он в душе. А вредитель.

Comment: Да, был уже подобный [вопросик](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12267/Модератор-чересчур-рьяно-закрывает-вопросы-Не-пора-ли-его-снять/12329?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C14.1582#12329). [И не один](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11830/Предвзятое-отношение-модератора-к-участнику-ru-so?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C15.3942).

Comment: @Глеб и что забавно, каждый из них всегда об одном и том же персонаже)) но всем пофиг)

Comment: @Глеб И в удаленных вопросах есть вкусное: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGx2j.png

Comment: @Глеб ещё вот [недавно было](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13087/%d0%9d%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82). Но в данном случае модертор ничего особо плохого не сделал, см ответ.

Comment: Is "severe psychological trauma" an accurate translation of your final paragraph? If you're genuinely claiming to have suffered "severe psychological trauma" from *having your questions closed on Stack Overflow*, I suggest you take a moment to step away from the screen and re-evaluate your priorities. It's really not that serious.

Comment: @F1Krazy, no "severe", but "serious psychological trauma". This is named "serious Russian humor". Get involved in Russian culture more often.

Comment: @Зонтик, скопирую твою цитату ⏩ "модертор ничего особо плохого не сделал". Это до чего нужно довести обычных юзеров, которые и создают этот Stack overflow ))

Comment: Я зашла на ваш сайт про кота, и поняла, что в космонавты мне нельзя 

Comment: Сайт создавался много лет назад , когда я  с трудом мог даже  2 страницы разместить. Для тренировок. Потом просто навешивал чужие скрипты с CODEPEN. По очереди. Там уже их переизбыток. Если сможете запустить чужую music box на 7 странице, ее что-то закрывает (я устал ее выкапывать). расскажите.

Comment: Если сможете запустить чужую music box на 7 странице, ее что-то закрывает (я устал ее выкапывать). расскажите.  => я увидела одностраничный сайт крутящийся во все стороны https://seregasmyfavoritesites.on.drv.tw/Site/Vivaldi/ семь страниц не заметила

Comment: да, вы правы. правильный кот в профиле. Замените vivaldi на tihomir. Music была видна, я нашел способ скрыть scrollbars с сохранением прокрутки. Что-то сломалось . Плевать на нее.

Answer (score 8):

Посмотрел я историю правок .. чат .. и согласен, что вопрос(ы) плохой(ие).

Grundy, возможно в этом случае, было бы лучше пройти мимо и не тратить времени, но он все же его не пожалел, пытался вам втолковать КАК надо вопросы задавать. За это ему тут только спасибо можно сказать, и пожалеть, что потратил он это время и силы на вас в безымянном тет-а-тет чате впустую (4 суток вы говорите, плюс свет?). Всем бы его терпение и выдержку!

Главный фейл мне тут видится в том, что **вы не понимаете, что ruSO это "Википедия вопросов и ответов", а не "Форум индивидуальной помощи"**. К задающему тут тоже предъявляются требования по формулированию и оформлению вопроса.

Ну или если вам проще в других терминах - когда вы статью в журнал даёте, или раздачу на трекере оформляете, или машину на трек выставляете - вам могут помочь с оформлением (метки поставить, мелкие опечатки, форматирование поправить, номер протереть, с толкача завести), но если у вас более серьезные ошибки (абзаца нет, мысль прыгает, скриншоты в heic, описание через пень колоду, колеса спускают, мотор выпал - то это исключительно ваша проблема и забота. Модератор вас не допустит и только вам на это укажет. Чинить вас - не его работа.

Comment: Видите, я не могу обратиться к @kromster, kromster — имя удаляется. Я чувствую, что я уже почти в блокировке. Почитал я комменты, это длится годами, " и всем пофиг". Ну тогда понятно, пора мне заканчивать здесь. Пусть следующие приходят и страдают

Comment: @seregada когда обращаетесь к автору поста, под которым пишете комментарий, не нужно его тегать, он в любом случае получит уведомление о новом комментарии. Так устроены комментарии, система автоматически удаляет такие тегирования, так как они только засоряют сам комментарий. Это касается всех без исключения участников, включая администрацию и модераторов. Не надо искать заговор там, где его нет. Что касается второго комментария под этим сообщением, который я удалил, он показался мне [грубым](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct) по отношению к автору ответа, старайтесь писать вежливее.

Comment: Не драматизируйте. Вы не можете обратиться, потому что и так пишите под его ответом. Kromster в любом случае будет уведомлен. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/115

Comment: @aepot первый комментарий был отличной самодискредитацией, я бы его оставил. Но вам виднее.

Comment: @aepot, отлично работаете, как только про "модераторское единство" — коммент удаляется. У меня в профиле была ссылка на сайт. Который сделан мной, из кусков кода со всего инета. Кот мой. Смотрю, утром ее уже нет. Вы уже профиля чистите ? Где этот вопрос в моем профиле ? Или он открывается и только по прямой ссылке , и уже пошел отсчет ?

Comment: Хорошо, где-то меня уже упрекали, что под сокращениями я продвигаю вирусы. Шас полную даю, посмотрим , сколько провисит.

Comment: @seregada _как только про "модераторское единство" — коммент удаляется_ - я же вам явно написал, почему коммент был удалён. Других участников здесь и не за такое банили. Хотите выяснять отношения - пожалуйста, никто не против, но соблюдайте [нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct). Больше предупреждать не буду.

Comment: @aepot,  Nofate , Kromster хорошо , я вижу тут целую очередь из модеров и других учителей. Пошли упреки , что мой вопрос не для Wiki (а тот дубликат с 4 translate по кругу -- образец пользы  ? Не позорьтесь с дубликатами )  . У всех такие же глаза, подтвержденные гордым модераторством. Упреков много, только я не вижу конкретных  указаний , номер строки , где у меня неправильно оформлено ???  Приведены инструкции к авто, к Wiki  длинной больше чем сам вопрос  -- что угодно, только вы обошли самое главное -- что никаких ошибок в оформлении, или копии поднятых проблем в моем вопрос нет.

Comment: Где конкретно  неправильно ???  @Kromster "никто не обязан исправлять  ?" Известную ошибку в 2 байта ? Это как ? Хочешь, но молчишь ? Сам вижу, но вопрос закрою и другим не дам ? Или вот тебе результат за то, что пришел -- иди домой , сам себе  ищи ошибки. Найдешь -- приходи, задашь вопрос еще раз.  Kromster , объясни свои слова. И пожалуйста, каждый дайте оценку конкретно , без лирических отступлений, что вопрос откачен К ОШИБКЕ и заблокирован. Это вообще ни к какие ворота. Там в чате Grundy так и пишет -- "отмотал к ошибке и заблокировал" . Это называется паранойя ?

Comment: цитата Grundy  "@seregada, не нужно редактировать этот вопрос удаляя твою опечатку. Задай новый."  --- Где запятая, Grundy , так ты и код пишешь ? Давайте, поясните цитату, автор тоже может.
Это что такое ? Вы тут что  , мне дело уголовное собираете ?

Comment: я сторонник того, чтобы ошибок и опечаток не было, особенно моих и даже грамматических. Правильно @keyframes . А вот за ошибками модераторов  (да, они тоже встречаются, и моя тема этому подтверждение) вы сами следите.

Comment: Я смотрю, простые модеры удаляют комменты (например, где я писал -- не надо меня пугать банами) . А до удаления статей и подобных вопросов у них руки не дотягиваются ? Или еще остатки совести сохранились ? Даже интересно, у кого из отметившихся здесь ? Тема охранена, разумеется

Comment: Главная цель , хоть как то изменить ситуацию . Если я сам через это прошел, через 4 суток пустой болтовни и убитого времени, и для себя я уже решил. Да я уже больше ответов получаю от всяких роботов разного пола, чем от вашего образованного общества и модерирования -- быстрее и без нервов. Но хотя бы новые юзеры придут и не пострадают от принудительной модерации, методы которой вы тут сами себе напридумывали, сами себе бейджей навешали.

Comment: @seregada модераторы, которые упомянуты в вашем вопросе и которые ответили в комментариях выполняют работу стекОверФлоу на все 200 процентов уверяю вас, я вам говорю, как обычный пользователь не имея никаких интересов.

Comment: @seregada Вы сами себя накручиваете, никто не против вас это точно✅. И абсолютно согласна с отвечающим вам, что наоборот спасибо сказать, что с вами провели три-четыре дня. Если вам не нравится ресурс, можно не заходить сюда, но незачем ругать и менять что то в уже устоявшемся сообществе (вы уже спустя неделю еще не остыли) (хотя, если идея и правда дельная почему бы и да, но не в данном случае...). Я вам со стороны говорю, и абсолютно не предвязата ни к вам ни к ситуации